# Checking for empty value in Select Options

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

In page 1 I have:

```
<SELECT name="<%=MY_INDEX %>"> <OPTION  selected value= ""></OPTION>
```

Im trying to check for the `""` value of my select box in the next page using `request.getParameter` as follows:

```
if((request.getParameter(MY_INDEX)!=null) ||
   (!request.getParameter(MY_INDEX).equals(""))) {
```

But I have the following exception - the above check is being ignored:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "">
```

Can some one give me a clue to overcome this?

Comment: has MY_INDEX a value ? Check in your form what is name of your select

Answer (score 0):

Try changing || (or) to && (and)

```
if((request.getParameter(MY_INDEX)!=null) && (!request.getParameter(MY_INDEX).equals(""))){
```

Currently your code is checking that the value isn't null *or* it isn't blank, but you want to make sure it isn't null *and* it isn't blank.